# VBA Macro to delete row if cells in B,C,D,E,F & G all = "0"

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, row

I'm looking for some code that will delete all rows, who's cells in columns B,C,D,E,F & G all ="0"

Many thanks for any help in advance

Comment: do you mean all cells in row for columns ` in columns B,C,D,E,F` equal to zero, or sum of these cells equal to zero, or any cell in specified cells for columns is equal zero? pleace specify

Comment: Apologies for not being clear... I mean, for example: if A5 = 0 and B5 = 0 and C5 = 0, etc until G5, then delete row 5 entirely, for all used rows in the worksheet. Many thanks

Comment: so, you need sum of cells?

Comment: No. on certain rows the cells B through to G are blank. In this instance I do not want the row to be deleted. If the code deletes rows based on SUM(B:G)=0 then that would also delete rows in which cells are blank.

Comment: now it's fine, see one of the possible solutions

Comment: Works perfect (the 2nd one) ... Thanks Vasily

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        If wf.CountIf(Range("B" & i & ":G" & i), 0) = 6 Then
            Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

*Note:*

`COUNTIF()` can tell the difference between a true **0** and an empty cell.

Answer (score 1):

same algorithm as has been provided by `Gary's Student` but also has some difference, just for info:

```
Sub dural2()
    Dim Cnt&, RowCnt&
    RowCnt = Cells.Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious).Row
    For Cnt = RowCnt To 1 Step -1
        If Evaluate("=COUNTIF(B" & Cnt & ":G" & Cnt & ",0)") = 6 Then
            Rows(Cnt).Delete
        End If
    Next Cnt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As a different approach:

```
Sub DelLines()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, val As Variant, rng As Range
  val = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B:G")).Value
  For i = 1 To Ubound(val)
    For j = 1 To 6
      If val(i, j) <> 0 Or Len(val(i, j)) > 0 Then Exit For
    Next
    If j > 6 Then
      If rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Rows(i)
      Else
        Set rng = Union(rng, Rows(i))
      End If
    End If
  Next
  rng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

If you still have questions, just ask :)

*Done by phone, may contain errors or typos*